# How can I export .mobileconfig file from IOS10 to Mac?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, macos

I want to find the .mobileconfig file in the IOS10 that contains all basic setting information of IOS10 like (Restrictions, Passcode, Wi-Fi, Mail, etc.) and export it to Mac. How can I do it?

Comment: If you want to make a backup of this information to restore to another iPhone, use iTunes. If you want to capture the information to use in macOS, I'm not sure this can be done.

Comment: Thanks to you at first, I want to use this information to do some test of the IOS system. I know this file is a XML format file but I don't know where can I find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your `.mobileconfig` files from you iPhone/iPad backup (if you have an access to target device) as follows:

First, you need to create (or update) an **unencrypted** backup from iTunes.

Then you need to get a path to your backup. You can do this in iTunes preferences, in "Devices" tab:
[image]

Now you can search in backup directory for all `.plist` files, that contains `PayloadType` key and copy them to a directory on your Desktop:

```
BACKUP_DIR="PATH_TO_YOUR_BACKUP"
mkdir ~/Desktop/mobileconfigs

find "$BACKUP_DIR" -type f -name '*' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :PayloadType" "$file" &>/dev/null
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        cp "$file" "/Users/toma/Desktop/mobileconfigs"
    fi
  done
' sh {} +
```